# Summing a Nvarchar in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am a rookie in the SQL world.

Anyway - I am trying to sum a column that is currently stored as a Nvarchar. I have done some research and it ended up that my query looked something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(Nvarchar_Col AS INTEGER)
FROM Datatable
```

I have no idea why but I keep getting the error: 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be much better to store integers in an integer column

Comment: Missing a closing parentheses there... Voting to close as as typo...

Comment: `SUM(CAST(Nvarchar_Col AS INTEGER))` <- clossing parentheses for SUM

Comment: Also, just as a "heads up", if your table gets big (500,000+ rows) then this query is going to DRAG.  You'll have to convert every entry in the table and that's a pretty big operation.  Is there a particular reason why you're storing numbers as text?

Comment: Hey Sorry - 

I did have the second paretheses closed. But it is still giving me an error that looks like this.  SUM(CAST(Nvarchar_Col AS INTEGER))  but it is telling me    "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '4.0' to data type int.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."

Comment: @Kalmino  I just took over working with this database.  it currently does have over 500,000 rows and everything in the DB is stored as text for some reason.   Not sure who did that or why it is that way.

Comment: @Pdoyle2 can you update your tags with the correct SQL version? You have 3 different ones listed.

Comment: @Pdoyle2 Dang, that's a crappy inheritance :(.  Check below, scsimon is correct.  If your data is formatted as "4.0" or "2.5" or has a decimal at all, then it's not actually an INT.  You either need to convert to DECIMAL or strip off the decimal portion before converting.  Converting to DECIMAL will be much faster; stripping off the decimal portion will add a ton of string manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `CAST` #.# to INT from `VARCHAR` You need to do the following:

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(CAST(Nvarchar_Col AS DECIMAL(6,2)),0)) as Total
```

This will fix both errors you are getting.

**NOTE:** I used 6 precision 2 (####.##) for your decimal but you can change this to whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks @scsimon  This was helpful.  I recevied another error "Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."
But I was able to fix it adding WHERE ISNUMBERIC (Nvarchar_Col) = 1  I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL(SUM(CAST(paidamount AS int)),0) as paidamount